# Symfony 3.4 logger service

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

When I called `logger` service get this information message  in log file it's worked but write this message in the log file:

> php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "logger" service
>   is private, getting it from the container is deprecated since Symfony
>   3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection
>   instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User
>   Deprecated: The \"logger\" service is private, getting it from the
>   container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You
>   should either make the service public, or stop using the container
>   directly and use dependency injection instead. at
>   /home/****/###/PROJECT/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:275)"}
>   []

My symfony version: 3.4.1

Comment: without your code I can't help you specifically, but the error message is telling you what is wrong. Symfony services and dependency injection changed significantly between 3.2 and 3.4. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Comment: Oh sorry in code i get logger service and call info method

Comment: So don't do that.  Consider updating your question with a bit of code showing where you are pulling the logger.  And maybe we can suggest a change.

Comment: Could you share the code where it fails with ->get("logger")?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As stated in Symfony 3.4, the `logger` service provided by the `MonologBundle` and all other services, are set to private by default. [[sic]](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default)

To workaround the issue, the recommended method is to use Dependency Injection.
http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/logging.html

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
     public function indexAction(LoggerInterface $logger)
     {
        $logger->info('Your Message');
     }
}
```

Source code Reference: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/v3.1.0/Resources/config/monolog.xml#L17

For service definitions Dependency Injection is available when `autowire` is enabled. [[sic]](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html)

```
#app/config/services.yml

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    #enables dependency injection in controller actions
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

   #all of your custom services should be below this line
   #which will override the above configurations

    #optionally declare an individual service as public
    #AppBundle\Service\MyService: 
    #    public: true

    #alternatively declare the namespace explicitly as public
    #AppBundle\Service\:
    #    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Service/*'
    #    public: true
```

Then to Inject the Dependency into the service, you add the type hint for the argument to the constructor.

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MyService
{

    private $logger;
    
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
         $this->logger = $logger;
    }
   
}
```

if `autowire` is disabled, you can manually define your services to inject the logger alias.

```
#app/config/services.yml

services:

    AppBundle\Service\MyService:
        arguments: ['@logger']
        public: true
```

---

Alternatively, to force the logger alias to be publicly accessible from the container, you can re-declare the service alias in your application services config.

```
#app/config/services.yml

services:

    #...
    
    logger:
        alias: 'monolog.logger'
        public: true
```

---

Instead of overriding the value in the configuration, you can also set logger as a public service in a compiler pass.  https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html

**Symfony Flex**

```
// src/Kernel.php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

     public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
     {
        // in this method you can manipulate the service container:
        // for example, changing some container service:
        $container->getDefinition('logger')->setPublic(true);
    }

}
```

**Symfony Bundle**

```
// src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CustomPass;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new CustomPass());
    }
}
```

```
// src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CustomPass.php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class CustomPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('logger')->setPublic(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the alternative for commands is? I've tried `new ConsoleLogger($output)`, but this doesn't include useful context information.

Comment: @Adambean same process, simply pass the `LoggerInterface $logger` to your `__construct` for your command. See: [How to Define Commands as Services](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/commands_as_services.html) Otherwise what specifically are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: I did try that but the command would no longer be seen once a constructor existed. I think it's because my commands extend from an abstract "CoreCommand", where I put my common command functionality. However using the `Symfony\Component\Console\Logger\ConsoleLogger` class I can run  `$this->log = new ConsoleLogger($this->output);` in my core command's `preExecute()` function to achieve a similar result. (The messages are shorter/cleaner, but lack the context data.)

Answer (score 2):

`$this->container->get('logger')` fails because logger is now (as of 3.2) marked as a private service, all services are private by default, that means that these services can not be returned from the container, and must instead be dependency injected (The class constructor must take the logger as a parameter and become a property of the class to be accessible), or marked as public in the service configuration, and since the logger is a symfony component, the service configuration is within the symfony project, you'd have to copy the logger configuration from symfony to your project service configuration and add `public: true`, to access the logger instance from the container.