# get a config in Controller on Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, cassandra, symfony4

I installed the bundle to my project
https://github.com/M6Web/CassandraBundle

But when i try to reach this config in controller like this

```
$cassandra = $this->get('m6web_cassandra.client.myclient');
```

I got this error

```
The "m6web_cassandra.client.myclient" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
```

In the github page are not any info about it, How can i reach the config?

Comment: As the message implies, your should inject the client either into the controller's constructor or the action method.  This is the "new" way of doing things in SF4.  It's possible that you may need to create an alias for the client.  The docs should cover this.  "bin/console debug:container --show-private" | grep -i m6web" might help.

Comment: To provide a similar answer as 3.4 changed the behavior of public and private services: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332102/1144627

Comment: I changed public: false with public: true and then i got this error  - You have requested a non-existent service "m6web_cassandra.client.client1".

Comment: Where did you change `public` to true ?

Comment: @n3k in services.yaml  https://ibb.co/exbDsc

Comment: The default public value will be applyed only in services witch are defined in the same file. Service you try to get is define in the Extension Class of the cassandra bundle. As Cerad said, you should declare an public alias to the service or inject it in your controller.